# What's the use of <template> within a <template> in VueJS 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, templating

I'm trying to understand the use case of `<template>` and it's functions. Having referenced [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html), I'm still left fairly confused.

Considering the following code in *any.vue* file:

```
<template>
   <div class="top-right links">

      <!-- Why use <template> here instead of a div, for example? -->
      <template v-if="authenticated">
         <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">
            {{ $t('home') }}
         </router-link>
      </template>

      <template v-else>
         <router-link :to="{ name: 'login' }">
            {{ $t('login') }}
         </router-link>
      </template>

   </div>
</template>
```

Why would we use `<template>` instead of just a simple `<div>`, and how is using `<template>` different than say, using a `<custom-component>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right, in your case you should simply use this :

```
<template>
   <div class="top-right links">
     <router-link v-if="authenticated" :to="{ name: 'home' }">
        {{ $t('home') }}
     </router-link>
     <router-link v-else :to="{ name: 'login' }">
        {{ $t('login') }}
     </router-link>
   </div>
</template>
```

But let's say you need conditional multiple tags **without using a parent tag** :

```
<template v-if="ok">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
</template>
```

Read more :

- [Conditional Groups with `v-if` on `<template>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt)
- [`v-for` on a `<template>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt)

Answer (score 22):

From my understanding, using `<template>` will not render out extra elements in the DOM. It's especially useful when you are conditionally adding multiple elements that don't exactly need a parent `<div>`. If the `<div>` serves no purpose other than to conditional multiple tags, that can be done without having an extra `<div>`.

I typically will default to using `<template>` until I need a `<div>` or other elements as a parent container, mainly to apply styles.

Answer (score 8):

Any use of `<template>` inside the main `<template>` of `.vue` files means that we want to use an ***invisible wrapper***. The question now is when do we need to use invisible wrappers? The answer is simple: Whenever we want to use `v-if`, `v-else` or `v-for` directives for a **group** of elements (not a **single** element).

Therefore, in this case, we wrap all the mentioned group of elements using this:

> `<template v-if = " "></template>`

and by doing this, we simply render the content between the above `<template>` tag, no need to create a redundant `<div>`, and then after rendering, the `<template>` tag itself will not exist in the DOM and so it does its job well as an **invisible wrapper**.

Answer (score 0):

Content within Template tags will be rendered into into a view in a `.vue` file.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I don't understand why you would use `<template v-if="authenticated">` inside a template when you can use a `<div v-if="authenticated>"`...

Comment: @Michał, both scenarios above will work but if you need elements to be siblings or don't want a wrapper around multiple elements but still want to conditionally render them, you would use `template` instead of `div` as it will not appear in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

If you use a simple `<div>`, external CSS, images and other resources will be loaded even if your `<div>` is hidden using CSS.

Follow the below link for an explanation of why `<template>` was introduced in HTML5.

[template introduction](https://www.webcomponents.org/community/articles/introduction-to-template-element)